# How to make the status bar uncover the searchbar?

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar, react-navigation

I have an issue that the status bar covers the searchbar like the below snapshot which is not expected. Things are working fine on the IOS simulator. **Do I have to write some platform specific styles for this?**

[image]

I am using *react-navigation* and things in the pic is the customized tabbarComponent which contains the searchbox and the tabbars.

```
{
    tabBarComponent: props => <IndexHeaderTabBar {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Yes  do a platform specific style for your screen

Comment: @Jigar Thanks, you are right. I also found [useful info](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1478).